# How to write a test case for my code

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

Is there a way for me to write a test case for my code? Do i need to remove anything before i test it using a test suite?

I am new to testing and would like to know i can test the code below.

```
var hello = "Hello, ";

function greet(name){

//Requirement UpperCase
function upperCase(){
if (name.toUpperCase() === name) { //uppercase string
  console.log(hello.toUpperCase() + name + '!');
} 
else {
  console.log(hello + name + ".");
}

}
//Requirement last element
function namesArray(){
if (name.length > 1){
var lastElement = name.pop();
console.log(hello + name + " and " + lastElement + ".");
}

else{
  console.log(hello + name + ".");
}

}

//Comparing name//

if (name == null) {
console.log(hello + "my friend.")
}
else if(typeof name === 'string'){//will accept strings and return them.
upperCase();
}
else if (Array.isArray(name)){//will accept arrays and return them.
namesArray();
}

}

greet()
greet("James")
greet("Ruth");
greet(["Barry", "Kate"])
greet(["Kerry", "Mike", "Snake", "FOX"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually tests should be written before coding the businness requirements avoiding to write the tests with an implementation in mind.

First of all your implementation can't be tested because your function strictly depends on the object  *console*.
At some point, during the expectation phase, you'll need an output to use as comparator and in your implementation this it means modify the code returning a string or an object (like `greetResult = {message:"Hello, "}`) from the *greet* function.

Now ...
Try to forget your implementation details and think about a single requirement as a salable product.

Your customer (Mr. Foo) doesn't want to know your code details, but he wants a product that matches the asked requirement.

#### So ask to yourself (and do it the same for all requirements):

*When Mr. Foo accepts my product ?* -->  ***Which are the acceptance criteria ?***

1. #### The first requirement is:

> the `greet` function ***should*** return **"Hello, my friend."** ***when*** is called without parameters.

Mr. Foo knows that calling `greet()` should receives `"Hello, my friend."` and in that case will ***accept*** the product. (*not always true in the real world*)

2. #### The second requirement is:

> the `greet` function ***should*** return **"Hello, " + name + "."** ***when*** is called with a  lower case string parameter.

Mr Foo knows that calling `greet("tom")` should receives `"Hello, Tom."` and if so will ***accept*** the product.
Mr. Foo it' s not a superficial buyer and will calls `greet("jack")` or `greet("tOM")` before ***accept*** the product.
Also Mr. Foo is a foxy man  will calls `greet("TOM")` to verify that the product does'nt produce `"Hello, TOM."` string.
**This is know as test granularity !!**

3. #### The third requirement is:

> the `greet` function ***should*** return **"HELLO, " + NAME +"!"** ***when*** is called with an upper case string.

And so on ...
In this way you are testing your code in a positive way and you need to cover the boundary cases.

Here the *jasmine* tests:

```js
// source code


var greet = function (name){
  var hello = "Hello, ";

//Requirement UpperCase
  function upperCase(){
    if (name.toUpperCase() === name) { //uppercase string
      return hello.toUpperCase() + name + '!';
    } 
    else {
      return hello + name + ".";
    }
  }
  
//Requirement last element
  function namesArray(){
    if (name.length > 1){
      var lastElement = name.pop();
      return hello + name + " and " + lastElement + ".";
    } 
    else{
       return hello + name + ".";
    }
  }

//Comparing name//

  if (name == null) {
    return hello + "my friend.";
  }
  else if(typeof name === 'string'){
  //will accept strings and return them
    return upperCase();
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(name)){
    return namesArray();
  }
  else { 
    throw new Error("");
  }

}
 

// test code
describe("greet", function() {
    
  it("should return Hello, my friend. when name is null", function() {
    var act = greet();
    expect(act).toBe("Hello, my friend.");
    console.log(act);
  });
 
  it("should return Hello, name. when called with lower case", function() {
    var act = greet("tom");
    expect(act).toBe("Hello, tom.");
    console.log(act);

    act = greet("jack");
    expect(act).toBe("Hello, jack.");

    act = greet("TOM");
    expect(act).not.toBe("Hello, tom.");
  });
  
  it("should return HELLO, NAME! when called with upper case  string", function() {
    var act = greet("TOM");
    expect(act).toBe("HELLO, TOM!");
    console.log(act);

    act = greet("JACK");
    expect(act).toBe("HELLO, JACK!");

    act = greet("tOM");
    expect(act).not.toBe("HELLO, TOM!");

  });

  it("should return Hello, names and last name. when called with an array of strings", function() {
    
    var act = greet(["TOM","jack"]);
    expect(act).toBe("Hello, TOM and jack.");
    console.log(act);

    act = greet(["TOM","jack","giulia"]);
    expect(act).toBe("Hello, TOM,jack and giulia.");
  
  });


  it("should throw an exception when called with invalid arguments",function(){
    
     expect( function(){ greet({}); } ).toThrow();
     expect( function(){ greet(1); } ).toThrow();
     
     var functionArgument = function(){
             //... do nothing
     };
     expect( function(){ greet(functionArgument); } ).toThrow();
   
   // uncomment and cover the following case
   // expect( function(){ greet(undefined); } ).toThrow();

  });
});
 
// load jasmine htmlReporter
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

```html
<title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: In terms of formulation, I see you use "should" in every human sentence. What are the practices? Is it possible to begin by a subject (like, the cutting function, the parser... the thing tested)?

Answer (score -2):

you should add semicolons first. Otherwise seems fine.

```
greet();
greet("James");
greet("Ruth");
greet(["Barry", "Kate"]);
greet(["Kerry", "Mike", "Snake", "FOX"]);
```